# Why "select" options are hidden?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a HTML select like this:

```
<select name="something">
    <option value="a">1</option>
    <option value="b">2</option>
    <option value="c">3</option>
</select>
```

and I've noticed that jquery interprets that options are hidden HTML tags. The problem comes when I have to remove real hidden tags like in this example:

```
<form action="#" id="f">
    <select name="something">
        <option value="a">1</option>
        <option value="b">2</option>
        <option value="c">3</option>
    </select>
    <p style="display:none">hello world</p>
    <any_tag style="display:none">some text</any_tag>
</form>
```

If I execute this:

```
$("#f :hidden").remove();
```

all options are removed. The question is why jquery removes options? and what is the most appropriate selector to remove **only** hidden tags? (well or not option tags)

Here is [a test](http://jsfiddle.net/navi2000/G4Qnr/).

Comment: Seems to work fine to me... What browser are you using?

Comment: @lonesomeday: It seems to be broken as described in any browser other than Firefox.

Comment: options are removed in Chrome 14

Comment: @thirtydot You're right. Solution 1: http://getfirefox.com ;-) More seriously, that sounds like a pretty bad bug...

Comment: Good question, problem occurs on chrome, firefox works

Comment: Also does this is IE9 (8 and 7 too it seems)

Comment: IE8 is even weirder (not surpprisingly). Here's the alert: `<SELECT name=something>   </SELECT> some text</ANY_TAG> `

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could just add the functionality that should already be there :P

```
$("#f :hidden:not(option)").remove();
```

Answer (score 8):

Check out this jQuery bug report: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6293

Of particular note:

> Changed 3 months ago by john
>   Status changed from open to closed
>   **Resolution set to wontfix**
>
> Considering that every browser but Firefox
>   says that it's hidden - it seems like it's the other way around. That
>   being said, I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve with
>   :hidden/:visible on option elements. It seems like you should probably
>   be using :selected instead. Don't think this is something that we're
>   going to spend a lot of cycles on.

As a fix for this case, I'd go for what @Joseph has already provided:

```
$("#f :hidden:not(option)").remove();
```

..which works as intended: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/G4Qnr/4/

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`$(":hidden").not("option")`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you could simply wrap the hidden elements in a container of some sort, and use jQuery to remove the elements from the container:

```
<div id="foo">
    <p style="display:none;">hello world</p>   
</div>
```

Then, in jQuery you can just do this:

```
$("#foo :hidden").remove();
```

**EDIT**

Here's another approach:

```
$("#f :hidden").not("option").remove();
```

Comment: The problem here is that I'm using the Jquery remove to parse some HTML pages created by users... :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the why, but you can remedy by using the :not jQuery selector.

```
$("#f :not(option):hidden").remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G4Qnr/2/

Comment: That selector isn't quite right. `:not[option] :hidden` should be `:not(option):hidden`.

Comment: @thirtydot Thanks for the correction! Funnily enough, the code segment worked with the wrong selector syntax as well..